# CMake Error "No C++11 compiler available!" with MS VS 2015

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, cmake, mlpack

I'm trying to get mlpack-2.0.1 to work on Visual Studio 14 2015 (I'm using Windows) but have had no success and I've been trying for hours but keep getting the same error: "No C++11 compiler available!" Additionally, I've read a handful of other similar issues on Stack Exchange and none have done the trick. I'm confused because I've been using VS 2015 for months without any errors. Is it possible I changed some compiler setting there and didn't even know it? Should I uninstall visual studio and reinstall it? I've downloaded CMake 3.5.2 and its directory is (the .exe is in the \bin subfolder):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\
```

The CMakeLists.txt file for mlpack-2.0.1 is found in:

```
C:\Users\owner\Desktop\C++\
```

I've used the CMake GUI and command prompt to try to get this to work but have been unable to do the job. I'm not all that sophisticated with changing CMake code so any help would be appreciated. Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with mlpack:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5)
    project(mlpack C CXX)

    # Ensure that we have a C++11 compiler.
    include(CMake/CXX11.cmake)
    check_for_cxx11_compiler(HAS_CXX11)
    if(NOT HAS_CXX11)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "No C++11 compiler available!")
    endif(NOT HAS_CXX11)
    enable_cxx11()
```

especially with CMake/CXX11.cmake:

```
    macro(check_for_cxx11_compiler _VAR)
        message(STATUS "Checking for C++11 compiler")
        set(${_VAR})
        if((MSVC AND (MSVC10 OR MSVC11 OR MSVC12)) OR
           (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 4.6) OR
           (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang" AND NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.1) OR
           (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Intel" AND NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 12.0))
            set(${_VAR} 1)
            message(STATUS "Checking for C++11 compiler - available")
        else()
            message(STATUS "Checking for C++11 compiler - unavailable")
        endif()
    endmacro()
```

So you have to add MSVC14 to condition:

```
    macro(check_for_cxx11_compiler _VAR)
        message(STATUS "Checking for C++11 compiler")
        set(${_VAR})
        if((MSVC AND (MSVC10 OR MSVC11 OR MSVC12 OR MSVC13 OR MSVC14)) OR
           (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 4.6) OR
           (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang" AND NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.1) OR
           (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Intel" AND NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 12.0))
            set(${_VAR} 1)
            message(STATUS "Checking for C++11 compiler - available")
        else()
            message(STATUS "Checking for C++11 compiler - unavailable")
        endif()
    endmacro()
```

Try this.

Comment: And this will break again with the next Visual Studio version. Not to blame you, but this is just sloppy thinking on the mlpack side. At best an unknown compiler should be a warning.

Comment: @MSalters: Agreed, the best solution is to do not check compiler inside project definition.

Comment: That helped get past the "No C++11 compiler available!" error but now I have a new one that stops configuration: "Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIR)" and then "ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/armadillo_bits/config.hpp not found! Cannot determine what to link against."

Comment: @Jeremy: you have to download Backtrace library, build it and put it into CMake search path.

Comment: Just a hint: a more generic check would be `if ((MSVC AND MSVC_VERSION GREATER 1599) OR ...)`. But generally it would be better to change to the more generic usage of defining required [compiler features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html).

Comment: @AnatolyS okay, thanks. It's a library or just a single file?

Comment: @Jeremy: I have never seen before neither mlpack nor backtrace, so I do not know

Comment: @AnatolyS I haven't unfortunately. I tried to find a solution to this backtrace issue but couldn't

Comment: The backtrace issue is just a warning, not a problem.  Your issue is that Armadillo is not found.  Do you have it installed?

@MSalters: the original issue was a CMake issue: CMake, as of 3.0, did not make any way available to detect a C++11 compiler.  So this was the solution we had.  We were specific with versions we accepted because Visual Studio generally segfaults when compiling mlpack, and there's no guarantee a new version will work.  CMake 3.1 and newer have cmake-compile-features, which is a better solution, but I need to make sure that is available on supported systems.